# Use smooth streaming .ism manifest with MPEG-Dash

Tags: javascript, html, iis, html5-video

I have been trying to figure out how to get dash.js (MPEG-Dash) to work with .ism encoded smooth streaming files. As you can see from the link provided below they are using a .ism file. When I try to use my encoded .ism video, and append `/manifest(format=mpd-time-csf)`, I get the following error code in console: `415 (Unsupported Media Type)`

I am using Microsoft Expression Encoder to build the .ism file, however this is usually used with a Silverlight plug-in to stream the video. Is it possible to take the .ism and make it playable with dash.js?

[Embedding a MPEG-DASH Adaptive Streaming Video in an HTML5 Application with DASH.js](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn593606.aspx)

[Serving MPEG DASH with the Microsoft IIS Smooth Streaming Media Extension](http://www.bok.net/trac/bento4/wiki/DashWithIIS)

```
<html>
<head>

<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/dash.all.js"></script>

<style>
    video {
      width: 40%;
      height: 40%;
    }
</style>

<script>
    // setup the video element and attach it to the Dash player
    function setupVideo() {
        var url = "video.ism/manifest(format=mpd-time-csf)";
        var context = new Dash.di.DashContext();
        var player = new MediaPlayer(context);
        player.startup();
        player.attachView(document.querySelector("#videoplayer"));
        player.attachSource(url);
    }
</script>

</head><body onload="setupVideo()">

    <video id="videoplayer" controls></video>

</body></html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can [hasplayer.js](https://github.com/Orange-OpenSource/hasplayer.js) which extends dash.js with support for SmoothStreaming.

```
(function(){
    var url = "http://playready.directtaps.net/smoothstreaming/SSWSS720H264/SuperSpeedway_720.ism/Manifest";
    var context = new MediaPlayer.di.Context();
    var player = new MediaPlayer(context);
    player.startup();
    player.attachView(document.querySelector("#videoPlayer"));
    player.attachSource(url);
})();
```

Answer (score -1):

A different solution would be to use tools from Universal Streaming.

(I am not affiliated with them in any way)